# Using generic keyof for a set action, for both the key and its type

Tags: typescript

Finding it hard to explain this in clear terms.

Inside the Setter interface below, I'm limiting the type of 'field' key to be keyof Store ('name' | 'age' in this case).

Then for the 'value' key, I want to get the type of the value of the given 'field' key.

- So, if 'field' is 'name', 'value' has to be a string.
- And, if 'field is 'age', 'value' has to be a number.

This is what I have till now:

```
interface Store {
  name: string,
  age: number
}
interface Setter<T = Store, K extends keyof T> {
  type: 'SET_VALUE',
  field: K
  // for key: 'name', want type value: string
  // for key: 'age', want type value: number
  value: T[K]
}

// Should error
const invalidName: Setter = {
  type: 'SET_VALUE',
  field: 'name',
  value: 30,
}

// Should work
const validName: Setter = {
  type: 'SET_VALUE',
  field: 'name',
  value: 'hello',
}

// Should work
const validAge: Setter = {
  type: 'SET_VALUE',
  field: 'age',
  value: 30,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic `T` isn't doing anything for you, because you always want it to be `Store`.  So the first thing you should do is remove the `T` generic and replace instances of `T` with `Store`:

```
interface Store {
  name: string,
  age: number
}

interface Setter<K extends keyof Store> {
  type: 'SET_VALUE',
  field: K
  value: Store[K]
}
```

Next, it looks like you want `Setter` to be an [existential type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466), meaning that you just declare something to be a `Setter` with no type parameter, and TypeScript interprets that to mean that there is *some* value of `K` that satisfies the type parameter, without you having to specify it.  Well, TypeScript doesn't have existential types (without crazy workarounds) so you can't do that.

What you *can* do is make a helper function which takes an object literal and *infers* the type of `K` for you, so you don't have to write it out:

```
function asSetter<K extends keyof Store>(setter: Setter<K>): Setter<K> {
  return setter;
}
```

Let's see it in action:

```
// error as desired
const invalidName = asSetter({
  type: 'SET_VALUE',
  field: 'name',
  value: 30,
});

// works, inferred as Setter<'name'>
const validName = asSetter({
  type: 'SET_VALUE',
  field: 'name',
  value: 'hello',
});

// works, inferred as Setter<'age'>
const validAge = asSetter({
  type: 'SET_VALUE',
  field: 'age',
  value: 30,
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The asSetter function closely achieves what was aiming for. On T, its to not repeat Store twice and also allows the Setter interface to be used on other types

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
interface Store {
  name: string,
  age: number
}

interface Setter<K extends keyof T, T = Store> {
  type: 'SET_VALUE',
  field: K
  value: T[K]
}

const validName: Setter<'name'> = {
  type: 'SET_VALUE',
  field: 'name',
  value: 'thename',
}

const validAge: Setter<'age'> = {
  type: 'SET_VALUE',
  field: 'age',
  value: 30,
}
```

You could also do it without duplicating the key using classes:

```
class Setter<K extends keyof T, T = Store> {
  constructor(public field: K, public value: T[K]) { }
  type: 'SET_VALUE'
}

const anotherValidName = new Setter('name', 'thename')
const anotherValidAge = new Setter('age', 30)
```

Comment: Hey Filipe, thank you for the answer! That's definitely a good solution, the field name and value types can not go out of sync with the defined generic key. But still is there any way to avoid the duplication?

Comment: Thanks for the help, really appreciate it. You've given me a few different ways to think about it